# ¿Qué está mal en este programa?

Tags: bash, variables

```
#!/bin/bash

#Inserta la fecha de hoy
MONTH='date +%m'
DAY='date +%d'
if [ "$MONTH" -le $3 ]
then #ene a mar
    echo "Falta muchisimo tiempo para Navidad"
elif [ "$MONTH" -gt $3 -a "$MONTH" -le $6 ]
then #abr a jun
    echo "Todavia falta mucho para Navidad"
elif [ "$MONTH" -gt 6 -a "$MONTH" -le 9 ]
then #jul a sep
    echo "Calma, pronto empezaremos a pensar en Navidad"
elif [ "$MONTH" -gt 9 -a "$MONTH" -lt 12 ]
then #oct a nov
    echo "¡Casi nada para Navidad!"
elif [ "$MONTH" -eq 12 ]
then #Es dic - revisa el día
    if [ "$DAY" -ge l -a "$DAY" -le 18 ]
    then #Hasta el 18
        echo "Solo unos días para Navidad"
    elif [ "$DAY" -gt 18 -a "$DAY" -le 24 ]
    then # 20 a 24
        echo "Menos de una semana para Navidad"
    elif [ "$DAY" -eq 25 ]
    then # Es navidad
        echo ¡Feliz Navidad!
    elif [ "$DAY" -ge 26 -a "$DAY" -le 31 ]
    then # Despues de Navidad
        echo "Bueno, eso fue Navidad!"
    else #Algo salió mal con la fecha
        echo "Estás seguro de la fecha?"
    exit 1
    fi
else #Algo salió mal con la fecha
    echo "Estás seguro de la fecha?"
    exit 1
fi
```

Me marca error en las líneas de las variables del mes y día, me gustaría saber cual es el error o si las funciones utilizadas no son las correctas, así como si se puede mejorar o hacer más sencillo.

Comment: Hay multitud de errores. Tal y como se comenta en [la wiki de Bash](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) pega primero el código en [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) para las más evidentes. No podemos debuggar por ti, indica algo concreto marcando las líneas y dando un [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa *command substitution*, es decir `variable=$(comandos)`

En lugar de:

```
MONTH='date +%m'
DAY='date +%d'
```

Haz

```
MONTH=$(date +%m)
DAY=$(date +%d)
```

Ya que con las comillas simples sólo estás asignando la cadena `"date +etc..."` a las variables correspondientes, en cambio, con *command substitution* asignas el *stdout* de la subshell a las variables.

Comment: Gracias, si era eso!

Comment: Que bien, si te sirvió mi respuesta, márcala como la correcta.